# Custom commands whithin page object model command debugging

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

Problem: No execution after certain custom command execution whithin page object model command. There are no errors reported. The browser stays on the page and the commands that follow do not get executed. If the troublesom custom command gets commented out all the other commands get executed including submit button. If the troublesom custom commands gets moved just before the submit button all the commands get executed troublesome command including but submit button does not get clicked. There are no errors in any of the above cases.

Any suggestion how to troubleshote this?

page object model command: pomAllotShares
1st custom command that does not cause trouble: eCheckbox
2nd custom command that gets executed correclty but block further execution without logging any error: eSelectShareholder.

Thanks in advance for help.

```
pomAllotSharesFunction: function(shares){

    var browser = this;
    browser.waitForElementVisible('@effectiveDate', timeInMilisec);
    browser.setValue('@effectiveDate', shares.allotment.effectiveDate);

    if(shares.allotment.incorporatorShares !== ""){
        var check = shares.allotment.incorporatorShares == 1 ? 'check' : 'uncheck';
        browser.ecorpCheckbox('@incorporatorShares', check);
    }

    browser.setValue('@quantity', shares.source.quantity);

    if(shares.source.cashConsideration !== ""){
        browser.setValue('@cashConsideration', shares.source.cashConsideration);
    }

    var elementLocator = '#ContactModal2-table > tbody > tr' + '[data-contactname="' + shares.target.shareholder + '"]';
    browser.ecorpSelectShareholder('@targetShareholder', elementLocator);
```

...

```
    if(shares.target.subjectToShareholdersAgreement !== ""){
        var check = shares.target.subjectToShareholdersAgreement == 1 ? 'check' : 'uncheck';
        browser.ecorpCheckbox('@subjectToShareholdersAgreement', check);
    }

    browser.click('@save');
}


// check or uncheck the checkbox
exports.command = function(locator, check) {
var timeInMilisec = 2000;

// preserve the value of this since its scope changes trhoughout the code
browser = this;

//get the element
browser.element('css selector',locator, function(response){
    //read element value
    browser.elementIdSelected(response.value.ELEMENT, function(result){
        if(result.value === false){
            if (check === "check"){
                browser.click(locator);
            }
        }else {
            if(check !== "check"){
                browser.click(locator);
            }
        };
    });

});


//select shareholder
exports.command = function(locator, valueToClick) {
var timeInMilisec = 2000;

return this
    .waitForElementVisible(locator, timeInMilisec)
    .click(locator)
    .waitForElementVisible(valueToClick, timeInMilisec)
    .click(valueToClick);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: return statement was missing from the custom command function.